# Minimization of a three variables function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, math, minimize

I'm trying to use an example of minimizing functions, given in Matlab docs and run it in Matlab R2016a but it yields an error.
Here's the example:
[image]

This is the code I wrote based on that:

```
function b = test_algo(v)
x = v(1);
y = v(2);
z = v(3);
b = x.^2 + 2.5*sin(y) - z^2*x^2*y^2;

v = [-0.6 -1.2 0.135];
a = fminsearch(@test_algo,v);

disp('a', a);
```

But instead of expected result i get an error:

```
Not enough input arguments.

Error in test_algo (line 3)
x = v(1);
```

Any idea why? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you execute your code, you have to put the call of `fminsearch` in a separate function:

```
function test()

v = [-0.6 -1.2 0.135];
a = fminsearch(@test_algo,v);

disp(a);

function b = test_algo(v)
x = v(1);
y = v(2);
z = v(3);
b = x.^2 + 2.5*sin(y) - z^2*x^2*y^2;
```

The above sample works for me, if I put everything in a m-file and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the objective function `test_algo` separately from the code that calls it. Since you don't need much code to define your objective function, you can use an anonymous function to define it:

```
b = @(v) v(1).^2 + 2.5*sin(v(2)) - v(3)^2*v(1)^2*v(2)^2;
v0 = [-0.6 -1.2 0.135];
a = fminsearch(b,v0);
disp(a);
```